# what is the use of CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH

Tags: cmake, compiler-flags

what is CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH used for? I have a install_config.sh file which says 
 CMAKE_FLAGS="-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=/usr/lib/OGRE/cmake/ "

i assumed that it is the path where libs generated would be copied, but i found that the cmake_flags are called when cmake is invoked. I guess the cmake cache stores it and uses the path while "make install" is invoked.

can anyone please clarify?

Comment: Variable [CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX.html) is install location of the package. Suffix `:PATH` denotes variable's type, which is used e.g. in graphical CMake cache editor. These are basics things about CMake, it is strange that you are going deeper into other's script without knowing them.

Comment: Could you please look up the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX.html) first? Then feel free to ask if there's still something you don't understand.

Comment: @tamas: i had checked the cmake documentation at https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX.html before i asked the question. they have mentioned about cmake_install_prefix but cmake_install_prefix:path wasn't mentioned there

Comment: @user27665: But option `-D<var>:<type>=<value>` is described in the documentation about [cmake utility](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake.1.html). By the way, types of variables are described with command [set](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake.1.html)